# python copy and paste formatted string for word or onenote

Tags: python, string, clipboard, onenote, formatted

I have a paragraph and want to bold specific words in it, copy to clipboard for pasting into onenote. I can not figure out how to get the bold formatting to work. Here's what I have so far.

```
LL=L.split("****")
newlist = []
for line in LL: 
    newline = ""
    if line.strip().isnumeric():
        newline = newline + '<b>' + line + '</b>'
    if any(string in line for string in boldstrings):
        for string in line.split(" "):
            if any(word in string for word in boldstrings):
                newline = newline + '<b>' + string + '</b>' + " "
            else:
                newline = newline + string + " "
    newline = newline + "\n"
    print(newline)
    newlist.append(newline)
    
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append(' '.join(newlist))
r.update() # now it stays on the clipboard after the window is closed
r.destroy()
```

Comment: Does `<strong> </strong>` work?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166164/is-there-a-way-to-format-the-clipboard-with-italics-through-python).

Comment: It prints out the <strong> tag instead of interpreting it. I checked that out prior to post, I can not install klembord on my system.

Comment: Try the unicode `'\033[1m'`  instead of `'<b>'` and  `'\033[0m'` instead of `'</b>'`.

Comment: I tried that too. it gives me  [1mSTRING[0m as the output pasted text